# Stuck On Ubuntu ASUS ROG STRIX

Tags: asus

I accidentally installed ubuntu on my main C drive and i have no idea how to get windows back onto it.. I've tried a bootable windows usb drive and as well have a empty usb drive for the windows installation but the drives wont show up at all..

F9 or F12 wont work either whenever trying to factory reset

Comment: That is a windows problem. I seem to remember you can load disk drivers  during windows usb boot. Maybe you need to do that. But you really need to ask Windows users.

Comment: But i dont have windows, just the bootable usb drive for installing it.. as well got off the phone with asus tech support and said it was something i would need to ask ubuntu on.. I mean unless your referring to the advanced options for the windows 10 usb drive.

Comment: "how to get windows back onto it."  reinstalling windows is a windows problem.  If you want to get windows back as it was before you deleted it ... not going to happen unless you have a backup and even then you 1st need to install windows. Nowhere do you need Ubuntu except it might be used to create the bootable usb.

Comment: According to the video link on how to create and use the Windows recovery USB from https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1013874/ you need to hold down ESC while powering on the system, and then use the boot options.  There is nothing that we can do from Ubuntu to help on on that.  The ASUS tech should have known where to send you for full restore of your laptop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)